# Setting up Environment Variables for MAVEN in Linux

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, putty, remote-server

I am using Maven for my project and I need to set environment variables in my system for it to work. I have set environment variable for maven, but it also requires setting up Java environment variable. I am accessing Linux through Putty through a remote server.

I tried setting up `JAVA_HOME` environment variable but I get this error when I execute `mvn -version`:

```
/home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn: line 190:  
/home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java: cannot execute binary file  
/home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn: line 190:  
/home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java: Success
```

---

```
`+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -f /etc/mavenrc ']'
+ '[' -f /home/z222189/.mavenrc ']'
+ cygwin=false
+ darwin=false
+ mingw=false
+ case "`uname`" in
++ uname
+ '[' -z /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31 ']'
+ '[' -z /home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1 ']'
+ false
+ false
+ '[' -z /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31 ']'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -n /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31 ']'
+ '[' -x /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/sh/java ']'
+ JAVACMD=/home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java
+ '[' '!' -x /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java ']'
+ '[' -z /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31 ']'
+ CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
+ false
+ MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS=-version
+ export MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS
+ exec /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java -classpath /home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -version
/home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn: line 190: /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
/home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn: line 190: /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java: Success`
```

This is the error i get with bash -x mvn -version

Comment: line 190 in mvn file is: `exec "$JAVACMD" \`

Comment: try to run it with a debug switch `bash -x mvn -version`

Comment: @Yuri Getting the same error

Comment: can you post an output of the `bash -x mvn -version`

Comment: please post the output of the  `bash -x mvn -version` within the question body. it looks like the bash can't execute the java's binary. can you run `/home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java -version`

Comment: it says : /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Why do you think this is an environment variable issue?

Answer (score 0):

You copied binary file(windows executable file) to linux directory and might set that location to the environment variables.

That is the reason you are getting the error. cannot execute binary file.

Download tar.gz file and un-tar and copy that file to linux directory using putty and set that path to environment.